# Map Reduce Intermediate Output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was referring to the map-reduce blog and it emphasised on writing intermediate result to disk. Here my question is why do map-reduce write intermediate output to disk can't it just use memory(RAM)? Is there some issue that needed this approach? Answer is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As Hadoop MapReduce is intended to be used to process multi-terabyte datasets in-parallel on commodity hardware [[1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Overview)], it will often not be feasible to store intermediary results in RAM, as most commodity hardware wouldn't nearly have enough RAM available for this purpose. Thus, disk storage must be used to store intermediary results for further processing.

Comment: How spark manages to do it the storage is the case?

Comment: @Manish Spark spills to disk for data that cannot be stored in memory

Comment: @OneCricketeer so MapReduce always does store intermediate output in disk whereas spark will store it in disk if it doesn't fit in memory?

Comment: @Manish MapReduce can be configured to use memory, too, I believe. It's just not the default